# What is the the best way to index a large mysql table?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance, database-partitioning

Here is the create statement for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `inodes_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `I_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `Stored` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `dataIndex` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `memoryAddress` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sens1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sens2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sens3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sens4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rawData` char(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`Time`,`I_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `i_id_time_idx` (`I_ID`,`Time`),
  KEY `I_ID` (`I_ID`),
  KEY `IX_TIME` (`Time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8289060 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=83
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(Time))
(PARTITION p2011_Prior VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_01 VALUES LESS THAN (734534) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_02 VALUES LESS THAN (734562) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_03 VALUES LESS THAN (734593) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_04 VALUES LESS THAN (734623) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_05 VALUES LESS THAN (734654) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_06 VALUES LESS THAN (734684) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_07 VALUES LESS THAN (734715) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_08 VALUES LESS THAN (734746) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_09 VALUES LESS THAN (734776) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_10 VALUES LESS THAN (734807) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_11 VALUES LESS THAN (734837) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2011_12 VALUES LESS THAN (734868) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_01 VALUES LESS THAN (734899) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_02 VALUES LESS THAN (734928) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_03 VALUES LESS THAN (734959) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_04 VALUES LESS THAN (734989) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_05 VALUES LESS THAN (735020) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_06 VALUES LESS THAN (735050) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735081) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_08 VALUES LESS THAN (735112) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_09 VALUES LESS THAN (735142) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_10 VALUES LESS THAN (735173) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_11 VALUES LESS THAN (735203) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2012_12 VALUES LESS THAN (735234) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_01 VALUES LESS THAN (735265) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_02 VALUES LESS THAN (735293) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_03 VALUES LESS THAN (735324) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_04 VALUES LESS THAN (735354) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_05 VALUES LESS THAN (735385) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_06 VALUES LESS THAN (735415) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735446) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_08 VALUES LESS THAN (735477) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_09 VALUES LESS THAN (735507) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_10 VALUES LESS THAN (735538) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_11 VALUES LESS THAN (735568) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2013_12 VALUES LESS THAN (735599) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_01 VALUES LESS THAN (735630) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_02 VALUES LESS THAN (735658) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_03 VALUES LESS THAN (735689) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_04 VALUES LESS THAN (735719) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_05 VALUES LESS THAN (735750) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_06 VALUES LESS THAN (735780) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735811) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_08 VALUES LESS THAN (735842) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_09 VALUES LESS THAN (735872) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_10 VALUES LESS THAN (735903) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_11 VALUES LESS THAN (735933) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2014_12 VALUES LESS THAN (735964) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_01 VALUES LESS THAN (735995) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_02 VALUES LESS THAN (736023) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_03 VALUES LESS THAN (736054) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_04 VALUES LESS THAN (736084) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_05 VALUES LESS THAN (736115) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_06 VALUES LESS THAN (736145) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_07 VALUES LESS THAN (736176) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_08 VALUES LESS THAN (736207) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_09 VALUES LESS THAN (736237) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_10 VALUES LESS THAN (736268) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_11 VALUES LESS THAN (736298) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2015_12 VALUES LESS THAN (736329) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_01 VALUES LESS THAN (736360) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_02 VALUES LESS THAN (736389) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_03 VALUES LESS THAN (736420) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_04 VALUES LESS THAN (736450) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_05 VALUES LESS THAN (736481) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_06 VALUES LESS THAN (736511) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_07 VALUES LESS THAN (736542) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_08 VALUES LESS THAN (736573) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_09 VALUES LESS THAN (736603) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_10 VALUES LESS THAN (736634) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_11 VALUES LESS THAN (736664) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016_12 VALUES LESS THAN (736695) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_01 VALUES LESS THAN (736726) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_02 VALUES LESS THAN (736754) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_03 VALUES LESS THAN (736785) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_04 VALUES LESS THAN (736815) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_05 VALUES LESS THAN (736846) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_06 VALUES LESS THAN (736876) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_07 VALUES LESS THAN (736907) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_08 VALUES LESS THAN (736938) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_09 VALUES LESS THAN (736968) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_10 VALUES LESS THAN (736999) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_11 VALUES LESS THAN (737029) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017_12 VALUES LESS THAN (737060) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_01 VALUES LESS THAN (737091) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_02 VALUES LESS THAN (737119) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_03 VALUES LESS THAN (737150) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_04 VALUES LESS THAN (737180) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_05 VALUES LESS THAN (737211) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_06 VALUES LESS THAN (737241) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_07 VALUES LESS THAN (737272) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_08 VALUES LESS THAN (737303) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_09 VALUES LESS THAN (737333) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_10 VALUES LESS THAN (737364) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_11 VALUES LESS THAN (737394) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018_12 VALUES LESS THAN (737425) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_01 VALUES LESS THAN (737456) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_02 VALUES LESS THAN (737484) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_03 VALUES LESS THAN (737515) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_04 VALUES LESS THAN (737545) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_05 VALUES LESS THAN (737576) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_06 VALUES LESS THAN (737606) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_07 VALUES LESS THAN (737637) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_08 VALUES LESS THAN (737668) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_09 VALUES LESS THAN (737698) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_10 VALUES LESS THAN (737729) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_11 VALUES LESS THAN (737759) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019_12 VALUES LESS THAN (737790) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION pUnknown VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

The most common query run against this table is either:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  inodes_data
    WHERE  I_ID = xxxxx
      AND  Time BETWEEN 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx' AND 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx';
```

or

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  inodes_data
    WHERE  I_ID IN (xxxxx,xxxx,....)
      AND  Time BETWEEN 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx' AND 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx';
```

Currently, querying data from this table takes a very long time. If I try to pull one year, it can take anywhere from 15 seconds to even minutes. I have researched and am struggling to find a way to speed this up. Is there a better way to set up the index, and if so, could someone tell me WHY!? I appreciate the help.

Comment: **BETWEEN** where is the **AND** ie. **BETWEEN xxx AND yyy** ??

Comment: For what it's worth, partitioned tables can be a lot slower for `WHERE` clauses than ordinary tables. The query planner sometimes has to search all the partitions separately.  With less than 20 or 30 million rows in a table, partitioning generally hurts more than it helps, especially with recent MySQL versions and 21st-century server hardware. 83 bytes time 10 million rows is less than 100 megabytes. That's not much even if you multiply it by 10 for dbms overhead.

Comment: @BerndBuffen My apologies, I just left them out. We use them in the queries.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that MySQL would use either your `I_ID` or `Time` indexes already. To be sure you can use `EXPLAIN` at the beginning of your queries to see what MySQL's query plan actually is. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)

ie: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM inodes_data WHERE I_ID = xxxxx AND Time BETWEEN 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx' AND 'yyyy-yy-yy yy:yy:yy';` // Added `AND` statement

for more info: `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM inodes_data WHERE I_ID = xxxxx AND Time BETWEEN 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx' AND 'yyyy-yy-yy yy:yy:yy';` // Added `AND` statement.

<del>Additonally, you could create a compound index with both `I_ID` and `Time` which might create a better index if you always query with both columns. You would change your alter to add another index:</del> - Missed the existing `UNIQUE` which is already a multiple column index.

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: Going to test the compound index, and let you know if I see an improvement. Wouldn't it do the same as whats already declared in the create table here: UNIQUE KEY `i_id_time_idx` (`I_ID`,`Time`),

Comment: `UNIQUE` _is_ an index; don't be redundant.  Don't have prefixes: `(I_ID, Time)` takes care of `(I_ID)`.

Comment: I dont know how I missed the `UNIQUE` index, that would certainly be better than the `INDEX` I suggested. Either way, the `EXPLAIN` syntax should lead you to figure out whats causing the slowness. Note you should multiply each `row` value in each row to determine the total number of rows that MySQL is operating over, if you see a large number in the `row` column, it usually signals a serious problem with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really doing `SELECT *`?  How many rows will that return?  Won't the network time be the real problem?

If you are really summarizing things, let's see the `GROUP BY`, etc.  It can make a *big* difference on how to answer your Question.

Meanwhile, ...

Get rid of the PK and promote the `UNIQUE KEY (I_ID,Time)` to be the PK.  This will make the first query work optimally.  In fact, it will work noticeably better *without* `PARTITIONing`.

Don't have more than about 50 partitions.  The more partitions you have, the more overhead you are paying for.

Don't add partitions until you need them.  Again, 'overhead'.  Keep the 'future' partition and use `REORGANIZE PARTITION` when you add a new partition.  See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) for more discussion.

Shrink the `INTs` (eg, `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`) where applicable.

Get rid of the redundant `KEY (I_ID)`.  It is wasting disk space and slowing down `INSERTs`.

Get rid of the index on `time` -- it is almost always inefficient to have an index *starting* with the partition key.

Since the second query is begging for a two-dimensional index, I am not recommend removal of partitioning.  That is one of the few uses for `PARTITION`.

Don't say `CHAR(50)` unless the text is really fixed length.  (No, making the row "fixed length" does not help.)

Suggest using this construct for time ranges:

```
 WHERE Time >= '2017-02-01`
   AND Time  < '2017-02-01` + INTERVAL 5 MONTH
```

Summary:

- Clean up the partitions (fewer, no future, etc)
- toss `id`
- `CHAR` -> `VARCHAR`
- Change the 4 indexes to perhaps 1:  `PRIMARY KEY(I_ID, time)`

Comment: I will be giving these suggestions the good old college try, and getting back with you. Thank you very much for the response. As far as "GROUP BY" this is time-series data, and so grouping is not a thing.

Comment: Not doing things like average over a each day?

Comment: Possibly from time to time I suppose that may come up, but for the raw purpose of displaying the time series to the client which is 99.9% of the work load. In reality, I am just lost in a mess of data and have been unable to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: There are about 500M rows in this table. simply selecting the count takes AGES

Comment: A graph cannot effectively use more than a few hundred points.  Yet you are fetching a million rows?  My point is, there are ways to build the graph _without_ fetching "too many" rows, thereby keeping the query fast.  Please add to your Question a description of the goal; I think I see a way to make a query that runs 10 _times_ as fast.  Part of the description needs to detail how many days are in the query and how many rows that maps to.

Comment: @WilliamRiley - (continued)  For example, when graphing one year, do you really need more than 365 points on the graph (rows from table)?  Perhaps you will argue that you need to indicate the variation within a day?  Have you seen "candlestick" graphs used in stock charts?  I'm not suggesting candlestick graphs, but rather pointing out that 365 rows (with some extra columns) can satisfy such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163336/discussion-between-william-riley-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 0):

Build and maintain two "Summary tables".  Each table would have

```
Time (truncated to day for one table, hour for the other)
I_ID
3 columns for each sensor
miscellany
```

Columns for one sensor:

```
average for the day (or hour)
min
max
```

Depending on the Time range...

- For a range of less than a week, use the raw data, as you are doing now.  (We may need to re-address the partitioning and indexing to make this work better.)
- For 1 week to 6 months, use the hourly summary table
- For more than 6 months, use the daily summary table.

That way, you get at least 100 points.  Adjust the cutoffs as a trade-off between speed of query versus detail in graph.

If you like, you can display a vertical bar instead of just a dot -- this lets you represent how much variation there was within the hour or day.  The user can zoom in if he wants more detail.

The Summary tables can be non-partitioned, with

```
PRIMARY KEY(I_ID, Time),
INDEX(Time)
```

More on summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

For maintenance of the tables, do something like:  At the end of each your, run a query something like:

```
 INSERT INTO Hourly (...)
     SELECT FLOOR(Time / 3600) AS the_hour,
            I_ID, ...
            AVG(sensor1),
            MIN(sensor1),
            MAX(sensor1),
            ...
        FROM ...
        WHERE ...  -- just the one hour
        GROUP BY the_hour, I_ID;
```

At the end of each day, roll up the hourly into the daily.